# requirejs minifier breaks module loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs, production-environment, r.js, optimization

This is quite confusing so I will try to explain this problem in detail.

I've written an application using `require.js` and **everything works fine when the javascript code is not minified.**

## commons/js/config.js

```
 require.config({.... , deps : ['startup']});
```

## commons/js/startup.js

```
 define('startup', ['router', 'xpto', 'i18n!nls/messages'], function(router, xpto, i18n) {....})
```

## app/js/router.js (minified)

```
  define(…);
  define(…);
  define(…);
  define(…);
  define(…);
  define("nls/messages", ….);
  define("nls/pt-pt/messages", ….);
  define("router", […., "i18n!nls/messages"], function (…,i18n) { … })
```

Both `config.js` and `startup.js` are minimized and deployed together in a single servletpath /commons

The `app` is mapped in `/app` and there is an index.html with

```
<script data-config="/commons/js/config.js" src="/commons/libs/require/require.js"/>
```

Also in `/app` I've a `router.js` which will be loaded by the commons `startup.js`.
This will make commons `startup.js` to load resources from `/app`.

The problem occurs when loading router from `startup.js` dependencies. Since `router.js` has several define statements, **the `i18n!nls/messages` in `startup.js` deps will start loading BEFORE the define("nls/messages") present in router.js**, which triggers an `nls/messages.js not found` error.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance!